# Добавить *.exe файл в список разрешенных файервола.

Tags: firewall, windows, delphi, php

Здравствуйте!
Наверняка есть какие-нибудь способы добавления *.exe файла в список разрешенных файервола Windows. Может вы знаете, как? Спасибо =)

**UPD:**
Это сделать в принципе реально! Вот реализация на PHP:

```
passthru("netsh firewall add allowedprogram 
%WINDIR%\system32\myapp.exe TCPInfrastructure>nul 2>&1");
```

А как сделать то же самое, но на Delphi, десктопном языке?

Comment: Так при первом запуске диалог выдается - "разрешить" или "запретить".

Принимать действия за пользователя есть не правильно.

Comment: Так не катит, потому что связь с любым ресурсом внешнего мира из локального считается потенциально опасной...

Answer (score 2):

Эмм...

В легальном виде... это умеют делать конструкторы пакетов установок (Wise - точно).

В прочем виде это вероятно можно сделать через API вызовы или манипулируя с реестром. Но для этого точно нужны минимум права админа. И скорее всего UAC такое сделать втихаря не даст - и будет прав))

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос выше. Это реально сделать, например, на PHP!

Comment: Вероятно что-то типа: 

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open','netsh','firewall add allowedprogram 
%WINDIR%\system32\myapp.exe TCPInfrastructure>nul 2>&1', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

Comment: @SilverIce Уж очень вероятно. Не надо забывать о том, что это всё WinApi, соответственно надо подключить ShellApi

Comment: Это заморочки Дельфи. Я тут не причем)

Но это всё фигня. Вы получите массу удовольствия, когда обнаружите, что ещё бываю сети за NAT (вы ж фаервол ковыряете не для того чтоб были исходящие(они и так по-умолчанию всем разрешены), а чтоб были входящие к этой машине и вашей проге). Хотя, если софт локальный - то проблем быть не должно.

Кстати. Без прав админа работает?